# Android activity life cycle behaving weirdly

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

According to [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), the `onStart()` method of an activity should be called after `onStop()`.
I have two activities A(HomeScreen) and B(ChatScreen). B starts from activity A using intent. When I press the back button, activity A is called, but the behavior logged in logcat regarding lifecycle doesn't matches the one specified in docs.
This is the behavior when I press back button.

```
04-02 05:38:56.963  17694-17694/com.example.akash.chatapplication I/System.out﹕ ChatScreen.onPause
04-02 05:38:56.983  17694-17694/com.example.akash.chatapplication I/System.out﹕ HomeScreen.onStart
//Lines not belonging to lifecycle
04-02 05:38:56.983  17694-17694/com.example.akash.chatapplication I/System.out﹕ HomeScreen.onResume
//Lines not belonging to lifecycle
04-02 05:38:57.463  17694-17694/com.example.akash.chatapplication I/System.out﹕ ChatScreen.onStop
04-02 05:38:57.463  17694-17694/com.example.akash.chatapplication I/System.out﹕ ChatScreen.onDestroy
04-02 05:38:57.468  17694-17694/com.example.akash.chatapplication D/AbsListView﹕ onDetachedFromWindow
```

Notice the first two lines? Why is it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, the lifecycle is independent in each activity